# Ubuntu, apache - sudoers problem

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, apache-http-server, sudo, sudoers

I need to execute a script via php (php5.xx), server running apache2 (Ubuntu 10.04). The script needs to be executed as another user.

I added following lines to `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Cmnd_Alias SECURE_SVN_UPDATE = /path_to_script/just_svn_update.sh
#www-data ALL=(ALL,!root,!#0) NOPASSWD: SECURE_SVN_UPDATE
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SECURE_SVN_UPDATE
```

(I tried both lines)

And in PHP, I call

`exec("sudo -u theuser SECURE_SVN_UPDATE")`

I get the error

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

I tried setting

`Defaults visiblepw`

in the `sudoers` file, but after that, running the command from PHP gives error:

`sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts`.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this OR a method to achieve it without compromising security.  (I want apache to be able to execute just that script as another user, nothing else).

Answer (score 0):

Rather then trying to sudo execute a file, why not have an apache running for a particular virtual host as a user that you want to have the privilege to update the source code you are trying to pull down?

This link refers to the way of setting the user
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#user

Secondly if I understand correctly what you are trying to do is:
You have a webserver remotely.
You want to log in and have it pull the updated code from SVN.
Normally the methods for deployment require a more hands on approach like rsync, FTP, or SFTP/SCP push .